# How to open activity after Missed call android?

Tags: java, android, performance

i have develop code of call back on Missed Call number. in My code i confuse at which position i put intent on new activity. i also open activity at the time of Incoming Call. but At the time of Miscall i confuse.
 So how can i open Activity after Missed call .

### Code

```
 Context c;
    boolean cut, flag = true;
    PhoneStateListener listener;
    SharedPreferences prefs;    
    static boolean ring = false;
    static boolean callReceived = false;


    public MyPhoneStateListener(Context c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.c = c;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

        Log.d("main", "incoming call receiver.");
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) c
                .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        boolean isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();       

        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
            Log.d("flags", "flags: " + flag);
            if (flag) {

                cut = true;
                flag = false;
                CheckMissCall call = new CheckMissCall(c);
                call.setName(incomingNumber);
                call.setNumber4Sms(incomingNumber);
                call.setContactPhoto();

                Log.d("main", "state ringing");
                prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
                if (!prefs.getBoolean("main_state", false)) {

                    return;
                }
                if (!isScreenOn && CheckMissCall.isRunning) {


                    return;
                }               
                else {
                    Log.d("main", "EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE:  Unlock hud");
                    Intent in=new  Intent(c, Unlock_hud.class);
                    in.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
                    c.startService(in);                 
                }               
            }
        }       
        else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
            Log.d("main", "offhook");           
        }   
        else {
            if (cut && CheckMissCall.isShown) {
                Log.d("main", "Cutted");                
                c.stopService(new Intent(c, Unlock_hud.class));             
                flag = true;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: please refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665183/broadcast-receiver-for-missed-call-in-android) and after that you can put your intent to there.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490403/is-it-possbile-to-detect-rejected-calls-in-android

Comment: i do that all. but i don't find any code. @SercanOzdemir

Comment: i also do that all. @George