# Get alert dialog only after disconnecting call

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I am creating one app where I am using broadcast receiver to to get the number,I am trying to develop

1)while I am getting call and and disconnect call i am able to get number in alert dialog it works fine,but the issue when i make call from my cellphone and i then i disconnect i also want to get alert dialog with number,I do not know how to do that following is my code

**Problem**

Issue is..I want to open alert dialog only after disconnect call,either its is incoming or outgoing..

MyOutgoing.java

```
   public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        if  (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
           /* Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            if(null == bundle)
                    return;*/

            String phonenumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

            Intent i = new Intent(context, Disp_Alert_dialog.class); 
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.putExtra("Number", phonenumber);
            i.putExtra("type", "outgoing");
            context.startActivity(i);

            Log.i("OutgoingCallReceiver",phonenumber);
          //  Log.i("OutgoingCallReceiver",bundle.toString());

            String info = "Outgoing number: " + phonenumber;

            Toast.makeText(context, info, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "can you dig it suker", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
  }
```

MyIncoming.java

```
  public class MyCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {



private String incomingNumber;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if  (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

         // get the phone number 
         incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, Disp_Alert_dialog.class); 
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.putExtra("Number", incomingNumber);
            i.putExtra("type", "incoming");
            context.startActivity(i);
    //   Toast.makeText(context, "Call from:" +incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        // This code will execute when the phone has an incoming call



    } else  {


        // This code will execute when the call is disconnected
   //  Toast.makeText(context, "Detected call hangup event", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}


}
```

Myalert

```
 public class Disp_Alert_dialog extends Activity{

private String nums;
private String outnum;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent iin= getIntent();

    nums=iin.getStringExtra("Number");


    Intent iii=getIntent();

    outnum=iii.getStringExtra("outNumber");

//  Toast.makeText(Disp_Alert_dialog.this, "Got it"+nums, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    if(nums==iin.getStringExtra("Number"))
    {
        Toast.makeText(Disp_Alert_dialog.this, "eba andre incoming", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        builder.setTitle(nums);

    }
    else if(outnum==iii.getStringExtra("outNumber"))
    {
        Toast.makeText(Disp_Alert_dialog.this, "eba ander outgoing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        builder.setTitle(outnum);
    }
    builder

        .setMessage("Want to add in CRM?\n"
                + "If this call was New Inquiry,\n"
                + "Follow up or complaint call,\n"
                + "please add this in crm")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Add to CRM", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
            {
               Intent intent=new Intent(Disp_Alert_dialog.this,MainMenu.class);

               intent.putExtra("Nums", nums);
               startActivity(intent);

            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
            {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

 }
```

Comment: may be query the call log contentprovider.

Comment: sorry i dint get you..my question is simple i jst want to get incoming and outgoing call number in alert dialog...

Comment: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.provider.CallLog

Comment: i dont want callhistory..i said i want number in alert dialog after disconnect either i am making a call and disconnect or i am receiving call and disconnect..now you get??

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490403/is-it-possbile-to-detect-rejected-calls-in-android) maybe it will help you out

Comment: calllog have the number you want man

Comment: try to follow my code..you will get number in alert dialog when you getting call and disconnect,,but you never get number when you call someone and then disconnect..

Comment: Yes because `incomingNumber` will only cone when call is incoming.
Only way to get number in outgoing call is to get it from call log after call is over

Answer (score 0):

Yes because `incomingNumber` will only coMe when call is incoming.
Only way to get number in outgoing call is to get it from call log after call is over

[How to implement a ContentObserver for call logs] ([How to implement a ContentObserver for call logs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4422410/4481444))

Comment: I dont think that will work. Are you getting number?

Comment: I dont think you can get it that way. What i told you in answer is the only way I think.

Comment: Refer to the link in answer.